# How to prevent AndroidStudio Android Logcat from filtering my logs

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

`Android studio` removes some of my log messages while the app is running.
How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: _"Android studio removes some of my log messages"_. It does not. What makes you think so?

Comment: Because i know for sure long messages are printed, but when i search for them in the log, they are not there

Comment: Android logcat is a ring buffer. The long message might be gone from the buffer. Try increasing its size with `adb logcat -r <kbytes>` or `adb logcat -G <kbytes>`